# Dynamic body id

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I set ID for body tag in Rails?

```
<body id="login">
```

Comment: I have one CSS for multiple pages with different id.

Comment: so whats the problem with `<body id="login">`?

Comment: He wants to add it dynamicaly from view, as far as `<body>` is specified in layout file. And yes - it isn't clear :)

Comment: I'd have thought a class would be more appropriate than an ID, but I guess it would be much the same either way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set a variable @body_id in your action inside a controller or in your view and you can use it in your layout.

So for example if you have an action **index** you can add this code in your controller:

```
def index
  @body_id = "myid"
end
```

or in your view index.html.erb as:

```
<% @body_id = "myid" %>
```

Then in your layout, I suppose application.html.erb you can add:

```
<body<%= " id=#{@body_id}" if @body_id %>>    # no quotes around #{} are needed ;)
```

Comment: That's a bit hacky and brute :)

Comment: The problem with this is that you're defining presentation logic within your controller. Your controller should only be passing data into a view and let the view system worry about everything related to presentation.

Answer (score 25):

I don't find any of the solutions particularly elegant or flexible. Add a `body_class` method to **application_helper.rb**:

```
  def body_class
    [controller_name, action_name].join('-')
  end
```

..in layout:

```
<body class="<%= body_class %>">
#e.g output: <body class="articles-show">
```

You can then refine the above helper to dynamically inject other identifiers such as modules.

Answer (score 5):

You should use content_for tag here.

In your application layout:

```
<html>
...
<%= yield :body || "<body>" %>
...
</body>
</html>
```

And then from any view you can call this:

```
<% content_for :body do %>
  <body id='login'>
<% end %>
```

That's it :)

Answer (score 2):

Be careful! The following will not work in rails 3.1

```
<%= yield :body || "<body>" %>
```

It might look like it works but if you view source you'll notice your body tag is missing unless you override it. Most browsers will work around a missing body tag.

The correct way to do is as follows

```
<%= content_for?(:body) ? yield(:body) : raw("<body>") %>
```

Answer (score 2):

Be careful, you shouldn't be setting view data in your controllers, as some of the above posts have recommended. It breaks the MVC pattern, and creates needless objects that won't be used anywhere but HTML versions of your pages.

Another thing to be aware of is increased risk when you assign your body tag inside a logic block - why risk the page not outputting your body tag (breaking the page) if you don't have to? The example above:

```
<%= yield :body || "<body>" %>
```

Someone may not entirely understand your meaning in a child partial, and you're just increasing the duplication of the body tag, meaning you have more places to look if somebody doesn't terminate the tag, etc. There's no need for this risk. A more sensible solution is to yield just the class. HAML will allow you to supply optional class elements, eg:

```
%body{ id: yield(:body_id), class: yield(:body_class) }
```

And then set those values in your view:

```
- content_for(:body_class) { 'dashboard business' }
```

I'd love a solution that allows for multiple partials to add classes to the one yield block, but haven't found a non-hacky way to do this yet.

Answer (score 0):

```
<body id="<%= @bodyid %>">
```

and in your controller, you can set this

```
@bodyid = "login"
```

Comment: In this case I have two body tags in HTML - <body> <body id="login">

Answer (score -1):

U didnt really explain what exactly u need to do then, my first guess is:

```
<body id="<%= @body_id %>">
```

Comment: If u have static id why u need to set it then? Or am i really missing something here..

Comment: In this case I have two body tags in HTML - <body> <body id="login">

Comment: So u need to add id="login" to the body tag? then just do <body <%= @body_id %> > where @body_id = "id=\"login\""